# Best strategy to deal with multiple unexpected pop-up windows on SAP - DEP?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sap-gui

I created a script that runs through orders in SAP and changes their date. For this, it has to select first all of the items within the order and then proceed to change the date.

The script has several IF statements that deal with expected pop-ups on steps of the process. As you can notice, some of them are exactly the same because it might happen that two pop-up windows identical in structure appear one after the other.

My question is, can I somehow make a list of the IF statements and then ask the scrip to run over it everytime it finds a pop-up window? I tried the OnError GoTo but it seems it looped throughout the list without selecting one of the IF statements.

I hope someone can shed some light on this. Here is my code, the OnError GoTo is inactive:

```
Sub Roller()
    
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim maxi        As String
    
    Set ws = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roll")
    i = 2
    maxi = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Do While i < maxi + 1
        
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")        'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
        Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine        'Get the currently running SAP GUI
        Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)        'Get the first system that is currently connected
        Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
        
        If Cells(4, 10) = "YES" Then
            
            '            On Error GoTo PopUpHandler
            
            If Cells(2, 5) = "" Then
                
                session.StartTransaction "va02"        'To directly Open a SAP transaction
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = Cells(i, 1)
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16").Select
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9100/ctxtGX_VBAK-VDATU").Text
= Cells(i, 2)
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9100/ctxtGX_VBAK-ZZWADAT").SetFocus
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9100/ctxtGX_VBAK-ZZWADAT").caretPosition
= 0
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17").Select
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9200/tblSAPLZV444_PRIMARYTC_RC/ctxtGX_REASON_CODES-REASON_CODE[5,0]").Text
= Cells(i, 4)
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9200/tblSAPLZV444_PRIMARYTC_RC/ctxtGX_REASON_CODES-REASON_CODE[5,0]").caretPosition
= 4
                session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"
                session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_PCATTA_CREA"
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(2, 10)
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, 7)
                session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
                
                                                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnZSPOP_PRIMARY-OPTION1").press        'Outstanding issues present
                End If
                
            Else
            
                session.StartTransaction "va02"        'To directly Open a SAP transaction
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = Cells(i, 1)
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16").Select
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\16/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9100/ctxtGX_VBAK-VDATU").Text
= Cells(i, 2)
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17").Select
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnZSPOP_PRIMARY-OPTION1").press        'Outstanding issues present
                End If
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9200/tblSAPLZV444_PRIMARYTC_RC/ctxtGX_REASON_CODES-REASON_CODE[5,0]").Text
= Cells(i, 4)
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9200/tblSAPLZV444_PRIMARYTC_RC/ctxtGX_REASON_CODES-TAGGED_ITEMS[6,0]").Text
= Cells(i, 5)
                session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\17/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4323/subCUSTOMER_SCREEN:SAPLZV444_PRIMARY:9200/tblSAPLZV444_PRIMARYTC_RC/txtGX_REASON_CODES-TAGGED_QTY[7,0]").Text
= Cells(i, 6)
                session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"
                session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_PCATTA_CREA"
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(2, 10)
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, 7)
                session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
                
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
                
                                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnZSPOP_PRIMARY-OPTION1").press        'Outstanding issues present
                End If
                
            End If
            
        Else
            
            '            On Error GoTo PopUpHandlerNONFTFE
            
            session.StartTransaction "va02"        'To directly Open a SAP transaction
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = Cells(i, 1)
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            
                            If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
            
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/subSUBSCREEN_BUTTONS:SAPMV45A:4050/btnBT_MKAL").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]/menu[1]/menu[3]").Select
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRV45A-S_ETDAT").Text = Cells(i, 2)
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRV45A-S_EZEIT").SetFocus
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRV45A-S_EZEIT").caretPosition = 0
            session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[7]").press
            
                                        If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                                            If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                                                            If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[2]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
            
            session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_PCATTA_CREA"
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(2, 10)
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, 7)
            session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
            
                                                                        If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
            
            
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLZV01_IBERIATC_OTIFVAL/ctxtX_OTIFVAL-RCODE[3,0]").Text
= Cells(i, 4)
            
                                                                        If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
                
                                                            If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
                    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
                End If
            
        End If
        
        Range("H" & i) = "RDD updated And attachment added."
        
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "RDDs have been updated accordingly To the request."
    
    Exit Sub
    
    'PopUpHandler:
    '
    '    If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
    '        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
    '    End If
    '
    '        If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
    '        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnZSPOP_PRIMARY-OPTION1").press        'Outstanding issues present
    '    End If
    '
    '    Resume
    
    'PopUpHandlerNONFTFE:
    '
    '    If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[2]" Then
    '        session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Credit check (maximum % for open items exceeded pop-up
    '    End If
    '
    '    If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[2]" Then
    '        session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press        'Consider subsequent documents pop-up
    '    End If
    '
    '    Resume
     End Sub
```

Comment: Put the list of `If` statements in a new sub and call it? You could even make a while loop and keep running the statements until it can't find the pop up window anymore

Comment: So that your question goes direct to the point, you might wish to remove many lines from the code, which are useless (with regards to the question). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following error/message handling strategy useful in sapgui. I have some custom functions that get the window count, text message and window title. I then just add new messages and respond as I need to plus a catch all at the end.

```
Do While guiWindowCount <> 0
    msReturnMessage = guiGetWindowText(session.ActiveWindow)
    msWndTitle = guiGetWindowTitle
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(1, msWndTitle, "window title", vbTextCompare)
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnCANCEL").press
            msReturnMessage = "Custom error return message"
            GoTo FAIL_EXIT
        Case InStr(1, msReturnMessage , "message text", vbTextCompare)
            session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
            GoTo FAIL_EXIT
        Case Else
            If gbDebugMode then
                Stop
                Debug.Print msWndTitle, msReturnMessage
            Else
                msReturnMessage = "Error: " & msWndTitle & "; " & msReturnMessage
                GoTo FAIL_EXIT                    
            End If
    End Select
Loop
```

I also use the same startegy to handle status bar messages as follows;

```
If Not guiStatusBarErrorCheck(msReturnMessage) Then
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(1, msReturnMessage, "status bar message text", vbTextCompare)
            msReturnMessage = "Error: " & msReturnMessage
            GoTo FAIL_EXIT
        Case Else
            If gbDebugMode Then
                Stop
                Debug.Print msReturnMessage
            Else
                msReturnMessage = "Error: " & msReturnMessage
                GoTo FAIL_EXIT
            End If
    End Select
End If
```